# Magento 2.4 How to disabled / hide "Delete" from Catalog Products Actions

Tags: catalog, products, delete

I have an improvement problem;
I want to restrict some more things from that user. I want to block "delete" the product

Magento 2.4 How to disable/hide "Delete" from Catalog Products Actions

Ver.: Magento 2.4.4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 used UI Component to render products grid at admin, you can remove delete action at: magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml:

```
<action name="delete">
<settings>
    <confirm>
        <message translate="true">Delete selected items? 
    </message>
        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
    </confirm>
    <url path="catalog/product/massDelete"/>
    <type>delete</type>
    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
</settings>
```

and you can restrict delete action for specific user by create a after plugin for "Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction" class "isActionAllowed()" method.

Add plugin configuration in etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction">
    <plugin name="restrict_delete_product" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\MassAction" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction as ProductMassAction;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

class MassAction
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    public function __construct(
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
    }

    public function afterIsActionAllowed(ProductMassAction $subject, $result, $actionType)
    {
        $isAllow = $this->authorization->isAllowed("Vendor_Module::resource_id");
        if (($actionType == "delete") && (!$isAllow)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create di.xml on path
   app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml\

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction">
    <plugin name="hide_delete_from_catalog_massaction" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

2. Then, create a “MassAction.php” file on path app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\

---

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product;

 class MassAction
    {
        public function afterIsActionAllowed(
            \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction $subject,
            $isAllowed,
            $actionType)
        {
            if ($actionType == 'delete')
            {
                return false;
            }
            return $isAllowed;
        }
    }
```

[image: "Delete" from Catalog Products Actions]